# How minor of a case is a class appropriate for?

Tags: c++, composition

I'm trying to use composition in an `Entity` class of mine. So far, an Entity "is" `Displayable`(inherited an ABC), and "has" a `Position`(contains a point-like class). I know I will want my Entity to "have" a/some health, so I started defining a `Health` class to be composed into `Entity`. It was super-simplistic though, and only ended up containing 2 methods: `hurt`, and `heal` that modify its single field: `hp`.

If I intended to inherit from `Health`, I guess this would be OK, as it wouldn't require any boilerplate inside of `Entity`; it would just inherit the methods.

If I'm going to compose with it though, so for me to `hurt` an `Entity`, I'll have to route the `hurt`/`heal` call to their `Health` member and call their own `hurt`/`heal` method. With a class this simple, that means I'll basically have all of `Health`'s methods duplicated in `Entity`.

In a case like this, is there any point in defining `Health`? The simpler alternative would be to just give `Entity` a `hp` field, and give it the `hurt` and `heal` methods directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the underlying hp value is not public, it doesn't matter too much either way. Having Entity::hurt()/heal() directly access a private hp member is fine, and making them wrappers for a Health::hurt()/heal() call is also fine.

Assuming it's not public, I would base the decision on what you expect to happen in the future. Will health probably be a simple integer forever? Or do you think it'll turn into a non-trivial class with methods like getTimesHurt(), getLastHealValue() or getPoisonTicksRemaining()? You may not know for sure, but you can make a well-educated guess based on what kind of game you're making.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't consider "effects" that I might need to add later. Originally, I just wanted to increment/decrement the health value, but I guess I should look at the reusable big-picture. Thanks. I'll make it into it's own class in case I want to add on to it later.